# How to find all configurations of a boolean 3x3 grid algorithm

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm

**I need to calculate all unique configurations of a 3x3 boolean grid.**

- I have a 3 by 3 grid.
- The center is the reference point.
- Each tile surrounding the center can be either `true`, or `false`.
- If 1 or more tiles is in the true state, it is a configuration.
- Due to the fact that I need a way to count the number of `true` entries per configuration, each grid cell is assigned a number.
- I have developed a series of numbers that can be combined in infinite configurations of 8 or less without yielding duplicates: `(1,5,9,11,290,31,73,990)`
- when all numbers are added up in a configuration, they sum to a unique number that can be used to identify that configuration. Thus this is a really useful boolean grid system.

---

The truth table for this grid is as follows:

```
1,  5,  9,
11, 0,  290,
31, 73, 990
```

If center tile has 1 connection, it has 8 possibilities:

```
[1,5,9,11,290,31,73,990]
```

If center tile has 2 connections, it has these possibilities:

```
[6, 10, 12, 291, 32, 74, 991, 14, 16, 295, 36, 78, 995, 20, 299, 40,
82, 999, 301, 42, 84, 1001, 321, 363, 1280, 104, 1021, 1063
```

I have broken the first two configuration groups into rows.(this first is omitted as it is the configuration where only one cell is true at a time)

```
    void Row2()
    {
        list = new List<string>();
        int [] t = new int [] {1,5,9,11,290,31,73,990};
        string s = "[";
        int start = 0;
        for (int i = start; i < t.Length; i++
        {
            for(int j = i + 1; j < t.Length; j++)
            {
                int o = t[i]+ t[j];
                if(i == 0 && j == 1)
                { 
                    s += o.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    s += ", "  + o;
                }
            } 
            start++;
        }
        s = s + "]";
        list.Add(s); 
    }
```

Comment: Why not 1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128? Then you can do a popcount.

Comment: I think pop count is a bit too advanced for me.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.intrinsics.x86.popcnt.popcount?view=netcore-3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative approach.

1. Represent the 3*3 grid with 0 & 1. If the center has a connection with an element 1 if not 0.

   1 0 0
   0 0 1
   1 1 1

The above configuration means the center has 5 connections, top-left, right, bottom-left, bottom, bottom-right.

2. This configuration can be represented as 8-bit int. Smallest is 0000 0000 - no connections and the highest is 1111 1111 - all connections. And all the numbers between these two numbers represent one unique combination.
3. If you need a configuration with 3 connections, run a loop from 0 (min) to 2^9 - 1 (max) and check if the number has 3 set bits [3 1's in its binary representation]. If store the number. At the end convert the numbers into 3*3 configurations.
4. Counting the number of 1's can be done in two ways.

4.1 since the number of bits are fixed at 8, take 8-bit masks whose job is to extract only a specific bit and add them up

```
bit1_mask = 0000 0001
bit2_mask = 0000 0010
....
bit8_mask = 1000 0000

bits = (n&bit1_mask) + (n&bit2_mask) +.....(n&bit8_mask)
```

4.2 using 2's complement as a mask to get the last set bit

```
c=0;

while(n>0){
n&=-n;
++c;
}
```

c will have the number of bits.